# Python script error sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:

Tags: python, sqlite

I get this error when I run the script and I cannot see the solution. This program is supposed to draw a giveaway from a sqlite3 file which has the number of raffle tickets for a user. And recently the program the gives that creates the sqlite3 file updated some stuff (The script is made by me) and I can figure out the solution.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Draw\Test\dave-draw.py", line 244, in <module>
dd = DaveDraw()
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Draw\Test\dave-draw.py", line 64, in __init__
self.get_viewers()
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Draw\Test\dave-draw.py", line 215, in 
get_viewers
''').fetchall()
 sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: viewer_id
```

there's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pdb
import random
import sqlite3

class Viewer(object):
    def __init__(self,
        viewer_id,
        twitch_name,
        beam_name,
        beam_id,
        viewer_type,
        rank,
        points,
        points2,
        hours,
        raids,
        gains_currency,
        gains_hours,
        in_giveaways,
        last_seen,
        sub,
        entrance_message,
        entrance_message_type,
        entrance_sfx
        ):

        self.viewer_id = viewer_id
        self.twitch_name = twitch_name
        self.beam_name = beam_name
        self.beam_id = beam_id
        self.viewer_type = viewer_type
        self.rank = rank
        self.points = points
        self.points2 = points2
        self.hours = hours
        self.raids = raids
        self.gains_currency = gains_currency
        self.gains_hours = gains_hours
        self.in_giveaways = in_giveaways
        self.last_seen = last_seen
        self.sub = sub
        self.entrance_message = entrance_message
        self.entrance_message_type = entrance_message_type
        self.entrance_sfx = entrance_sfx

    def win_chance(self, total_tickets):
        """
        Takes the total tickets (points) as a paramter and works
        out the percentage chance that the viewer has of winning.

        Returns the viewers win chance in percent.
        """

        percent = total_tickets / 100.00

        return self.points2 / percent

class DaveDraw(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.debug = False
        self.database_path = 'Viewers3DB.sqlite'
        self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database_path)
        self.get_viewers()
        self.calculate_total_points()
        self.assign_tickets()

    def assign_tickets(self):
        """
        Assigns each user a number range based on the number of
        tickets they have.

        e.g.
        10 1-10
        10 11-20
        30 21-50
        1  51
        """

        self.tickets = {}
        latest_ticket = 0

        for viewer in self.viewers:
            # skip anyone with no points
            if viewer.points2 == 0:
                continue

            ticket_range_beg = latest_ticket + 1
            ticket_range_end = latest_ticket + 1 + viewer.points2
            latest_ticket = ticket_range_end

            viewer.tickets = range(ticket_range_beg, ticket_range_end)

            # assign a range of tickets:
            if self.debug:
                print("Assigning viewer twitch: %s beam: %s tickets %i-%i" % (viewer.twitch_name, viewer.beam_name, viewer.tickets.start, viewer.tickets.stop))
            if ticket_range_beg == ticket_range_end:
                if self.debug:
                    print("Assigning ticket {} to {}".format(ticket_range_beg, viewer.twitch_name))
                self.tickets[ticket_range_beg] = viewer
                next

            for ticket in viewer.tickets:
                if self.debug:
                    print("Assigning ticket {} to {}".format(ticket, viewer.twitch_name))
                self.tickets[ticket] = viewer

    def calculate_total_points(self):
        """
        Gets the total amount of points awarded to all
        viewers.
        """

        self.total_points = 0
        for viewer in self.viewers:
            self.total_points += viewer.points2

        self.total_points_percent = self.total_points / 100

        print("Total points awarded (total tickets): %s" % self.total_points)

    def draw(self):
        """
        Picks a random number between 1 and total tickets, finds
        the user that has been assigned tickets within that range and
        returns the user.
        """

        ticket = random.randint(1, self.total_points)

        try:
            winner = self.tickets[ticket]
        except:
            pdb.set_trace()

        print("\n===== WINNER Twitch: {} / Beam: {} =====\n".format(winner.twitch_name, winner.beam_id))
        print("Picked ticket {}\n".format(ticket))
        print("Winner win chance: {:f}".format(winner.win_chance(self.total_points)))
        print("Winner's ticket range: {}-{}".format(winner.tickets.start, winner.tickets.stop))
        print("Winner's ticket amount: {}\n".format(winner.points2))

        self.display_viewer(winner)

    def display_random_viewer(self):
        """
        Displays random viewer.
        """
        self.display_viewer(self.get_random_viewer())

    def display_viewer(self, viewer):
        """
        Outputs the data on all viewers.
        """
        print("""Viewer ID: %s\nTwitch Name: %s\nBeam Name: %s\nBeam ID: %s\nRank: %s\nPoints: %s\nPoints2: %s\nHours: %s\nRaids: %s\nGains Currency: %s\nGains Hours: %s\nInGiveaways: %s\nLastSeen: %s\nEntrance Message: %s\nEntranceMsgType: %s\nEntranceSFX: %s"""
            % (
                viewer.viewer_id,
                viewer.twitch_name,
                viewer.beam_name,
                viewer.beam_id,
                viewer.rank,
                viewer.points,
                viewer.points2,
                viewer.hours,
                viewer.raids,
                viewer.gains_currency,
                viewer.gains_hours,
                viewer.in_giveaways,
                viewer.last_seen,
                viewer.entrance_message,
                viewer.entrance_message_type,
                viewer.entrance_sfx
            )
        )

    def get_random_viewer(self):
        """
        Gets a completely random viewer.
        """
        return random.choice(self.viewers)

    def get_viewers(self):
        """
        Gets data on all the viewers in the database and stores
        the data in self.viewers.
        """
        c = self.db_conn.cursor()
        viewers = c.execute('''
                SELECT

                viewer_id,
                TwitchName,
                BeamName,
                BeamID,
                Type,
                Rank,
                Points,
                Points2,
                Hours,
                Raids,
                GainsCurrency,
                GainsHours,
                InGiveaways,
                LastSeen,
                Sub,
                EntranceMessage,
                EntranceMsgType,
                EntranceSFX

                FROM Viewer
                WHERE Type != 1
                AND TwitchName NOT IN (
                    \'treeboydave\',
                    \'treebotdave\'
                );
                ''').fetchall()

        self.viewers = []

        for cur_viewer in viewers:
            self.viewers.append(
                    Viewer(
                        cur_viewer[0],
                        cur_viewer[1],
                        cur_viewer[2],
                        cur_viewer[3],
                        cur_viewer[4],
                        cur_viewer[5],
                        cur_viewer[6],
                        cur_viewer[7],
                        cur_viewer[8],
                        cur_viewer[9],
                        cur_viewer[10],
                        cur_viewer[11],
                        cur_viewer[12],
                        cur_viewer[13],
                        cur_viewer[14],
                        cur_viewer[15],
                        cur_viewer[16],
                        cur_viewer[17]
                    )
                )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dd = DaveDraw()
    dd.draw()
```

Comment: Well, have you used the sqlite tools to inspect the DB? Are _any_ of the columns you expect present. I suspect it is failing on the first one in the SELECT, and the schema is not being created as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

All your other SQL columns are capitalised, any chance that's why it's not finding the viewer_id column? Maybe it's Viewer_Id or similar?

If you sql execute 'HELP TABLE Viewer' and print what it returns, it will give you an outline of all of the columns in that database table, so you can make sure you have the capitalisation correct, or whether the column actually isn't there at all.

Comment: Can you post the output of 'HELP TABLE Viewer'?

Comment: SQLite column names are not case sensitive, and there is no HELP command.